# Remove z axis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following gnuplot script:

```
set xyplane at 0    
set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' pt 7   # circle
set border 15
spl 'N.dat' u 1:2:3:($5/10.) w p ls 2 ps variable noti
```

Where the file `N.dat` can be found here http://www.filedropper.com/n_1 .

I want to remove the border parallel to the z-axis that appears on the bottom-right side of the screen, see the following output of the above script:

[image: output with gnuplot 4.6.6]

Note that I am using the command `set border 15`. The number 15 in base 2 is 000000001111 , i.e. the four digits in the middle are all zero: these digits correspond to the vertical axes in the plot and they are all zero here, thus there should be no vertical axes at all, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node162.html .

However, two vertical axes are still there. In particular, you know how to get rid of the bottom-right vertical axis only?

Comment: I updated your question to include the current output, so we know what you are talking about. If you don't have enough reputation, just upload the image somewhere and post the link. Someone with more reputation can then include the image. Also, please see the help about how code is highlighted in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those vertical lines aren't axes, and you cannot explicitely switch them off. You can however remove them, if your plotting ranges are slightly larger than the actual x and y data ranges. Here, to remove the bottom-right line, I updated the yrange to start at -1e-6:

```
set xyplane at 0
set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' pt 7 # circle
set yrange [-1e-6:*]
spl 'N.dat' u 1:2:3:($5/10.) w p ls 2 ps variable noti
```

[image]

Comment: This works indeed, thank you. I explicitly switched on the bottom-left vertical axis, and I removed the additional vertical lines by changing the x and y range
#####

set xyplane at 0

set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' pt 7   # circle

set border 31

set xrange [-1e-6:4]

set yrange [-1e-6:4]

spl 'N.dat' u 1:2:3:($5/10.) w p ls 2 ps variable noti

#####